# How to make a global variable in ms access

Tags: variables, ms-access, global

and a value that i get from that form, i need to send it to another form. I need to know how to set it as a global variable and call it in another form once the original form is closed. Thanks!

Comment: Vote to close because "too broad"? Hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new module with this code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public YourGlobalVariable As Variant  ' Change Variant to the data type you prefer.
```

Compile and save.

In your two forms, *set* the value:

```
YourGlobalVariable = SomeValueToSave
```

or *get* the value

```
SomeLocalVariable = YourGlobalVariable
```